# Matlab : How to highlight GLYCINE residues in my Ramachandran plot?

Tags: arrays, matlab, bioinformatics, protein-database

I am trying matlab to plot ramachandran plot, without using built in command. I have succeeded too. Now I wanted to spot the GLYCINEs alone in the scatter array. Any ideas how to do this? (link to 1UBQ.pdb file : http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=1UBQ)

```
% Program to plot Ramanchandran plot of Ubiquitin
close all; clear ; clc; % close all figure windows, clear variables, clear screen

pdb1 ='/home/devanandt/Documents/VMD/1UBQ.pdb';
p=pdbread(pdb1); % read pdb file corresponding to ubiquitin protein
atom={p.Model.Atom.AtomName};

n_i=find(strcmp(atom,'N')); % Find indices of atoms
ca_i=find(strcmp(atom,'CA'));
c_i=find(strcmp(atom,'C'));

X = [p.Model.Atom.X];
Y = [p.Model.Atom.Y];
Z = [p.Model.Atom.Z];

X_n = X(n_i(2:end)); % X Y Z coordinates of atoms
Y_n = Y(n_i(2:end));
Z_n = Z(n_i(2:end));

X_ca = X(ca_i(2:end));
Y_ca = Y(ca_i(2:end));
Z_ca = Z(ca_i(2:end));

X_c = X(c_i(2:end));
Y_c = Y(c_i(2:end));
Z_c = Z(c_i(2:end));

X_c_ = X(c_i(1:end-1)); % the n-1 th C (C of cabonyl)
Y_c_ = Y(c_i(1:end-1));
Z_c_ = Z(c_i(1:end-1));

V_c_ = [X_c_' Y_c_' Z_c_'];
V_n = [X_n' Y_n' Z_n'];
V_ca = [X_ca' Y_ca' Z_ca'];
V_c = [X_c' Y_c' Z_c'];

V_ab = V_n - V_c_;
V_bc = V_ca - V_n;
V_cd = V_c - V_ca;

phi=0;
for k=1:numel(X_c)
    n1=cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:))/norm(cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:)));
    n2=cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:))/norm(cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:)));
    x=dot(n1,n2);
    m1=cross(n1,(V_bc(k,:)/norm(V_bc(k,:))));
    y=dot(m1,n2);
    phi=cat(2,phi,-atan2d(y,x));

end

phi=phi(1,2:end);

X_n_ = X(n_i(2:end)); %  (n+1) nitrogens
Y_n_ = Y(n_i(2:end));
Z_n_ = Z(n_i(2:end));

X_ca = X(ca_i(1:end-1));
Y_ca = Y(ca_i(1:end-1));
Z_ca = Z(ca_i(1:end-1));

X_n = X(n_i(1:end-1));
Y_n = Y(n_i(1:end-1));
Z_n = Z(n_i(1:end-1));

X_c = X(c_i(1:end-1)); 
Y_c = Y(c_i(1:end-1));
Z_c = Z(c_i(1:end-1));

V_n_ = [X_n_' Y_n_' Z_n_'];
V_n = [X_n' Y_n' Z_n'];
V_ca = [X_ca' Y_ca' Z_ca'];
V_c = [X_c' Y_c' Z_c'];

V_ab = V_ca - V_n;
V_bc = V_c - V_ca;
V_cd = V_n_ - V_c;

psi=0;
for k=1:numel(X_c)
    n1=cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:))/norm(cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:)));
    n2=cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:))/norm(cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:)));
    x=dot(n1,n2);
    m1=cross(n1,(V_bc(k,:)/norm(V_bc(k,:))));
    y=dot(m1,n2);
    psi=cat(2,psi,-atan2d(y,x));

end

psi=psi(1,2:end);

scatter(phi,psi)
box on
axis([-180 180 -180 180])
title('Ramachandran Plot for Ubiquitn Protein','FontSize',16)
xlabel('\Phi^o','FontSize',20)
ylabel('\Psi^o','FontSize',20)
grid
```

The output is :

[image]

---

EDIT : Is my plot correct? [Biopython: How to avoid particular amino acid sequences from a protein so as to plot Ramachandran plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216827/biopython-how-to-avoid-particular-amino-acid-sequences-from-a-protein-ao-as-to) has an answer which has slightly different plot.

The modified code is as below :

```
% Program to plot Ramanchandran plot of Ubiquitin with no glycines
close all; clear ; clc; % close all figure windows, clear variables, clear screen

pdb1 ='/home/devanandt/Documents/VMD/1UBQ.pdb';
p=pdbread(pdb1); % read pdb file corresponding to ubiquitin protein
atom={p.Model.Atom.AtomName};

n_i=find(strcmp(atom,'N')); % Find indices of atoms
ca_i=find(strcmp(atom,'CA'));
c_i=find(strcmp(atom,'C'));

X = [p.Model.Atom.X];
Y = [p.Model.Atom.Y];
Z = [p.Model.Atom.Z];

X_n = X(n_i(2:end)); % X Y Z coordinates of atoms
Y_n = Y(n_i(2:end));
Z_n = Z(n_i(2:end));

X_ca = X(ca_i(2:end));
Y_ca = Y(ca_i(2:end));
Z_ca = Z(ca_i(2:end));

X_c = X(c_i(2:end));
Y_c = Y(c_i(2:end));
Z_c = Z(c_i(2:end));

X_c_ = X(c_i(1:end-1)); % the n-1 th C (C of cabonyl)
Y_c_ = Y(c_i(1:end-1));
Z_c_ = Z(c_i(1:end-1));

V_c_ = [X_c_' Y_c_' Z_c_'];
V_n = [X_n' Y_n' Z_n'];
V_ca = [X_ca' Y_ca' Z_ca'];
V_c = [X_c' Y_c' Z_c'];

V_ab = V_n - V_c_;
V_bc = V_ca - V_n;
V_cd = V_c - V_ca;

phi=0;
for k=1:numel(X_c)
    n1=cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:))/norm(cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:)));
    n2=cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:))/norm(cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:)));
    x=dot(n1,n2);
    m1=cross(n1,(V_bc(k,:)/norm(V_bc(k,:))));
    y=dot(m1,n2);
    phi=cat(2,phi,-atan2d(y,x));

end

phi=phi(1,2:end);

X_n_ = X(n_i(2:end)); %  (n+1) nitrogens
Y_n_ = Y(n_i(2:end));
Z_n_ = Z(n_i(2:end));

X_ca = X(ca_i(1:end-1));
Y_ca = Y(ca_i(1:end-1));
Z_ca = Z(ca_i(1:end-1));

X_n = X(n_i(1:end-1));
Y_n = Y(n_i(1:end-1));
Z_n = Z(n_i(1:end-1));

X_c = X(c_i(1:end-1)); 
Y_c = Y(c_i(1:end-1));
Z_c = Z(c_i(1:end-1));

V_n_ = [X_n_' Y_n_' Z_n_'];
V_n = [X_n' Y_n' Z_n'];
V_ca = [X_ca' Y_ca' Z_ca'];
V_c = [X_c' Y_c' Z_c'];

V_ab = V_ca - V_n;
V_bc = V_c - V_ca;
V_cd = V_n_ - V_c;

psi=0;
for k=1:numel(X_c)
    n1=cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:))/norm(cross(V_ab(k,:),V_bc(k,:)));
    n2=cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:))/norm(cross(V_bc(k,:),V_cd(k,:)));
    x=dot(n1,n2);
    m1=cross(n1,(V_bc(k,:)/norm(V_bc(k,:))));
    y=dot(m1,n2);
    psi=cat(2,psi,-atan2d(y,x));

end

psi=psi(1,2:end);

res=strsplit(p.Sequence.ResidueNames,' ');
angle =[phi;psi];
angle(:,find(strcmp(res,'GLY'))-1)=[];


scatter(angle(1,:),angle(2,:))
box on
axis([-180 180 -180 180])
title('Ramachandran Plot for Ubiquitn Protein','FontSize',16)
xlabel('\Phi^o','FontSize',20)
ylabel('\Psi^o','FontSize',20)
grid
```

which gives output (with no GLY) as below :

[image]

Comment: As written, this is more of a biochemistry question than a programming question. If you want to remove the glycines, you will have to test your molecules for some property unique to glycine (i.e. psi<0 & phi>5 or something). In the linked question, there is an array with residue names and the user picked out the indexes that had the string "GLY" in them. It is not clear that you have such a character array.

Comment: @craigim : First of ll , I would like to verify code. I have modified the code, with characters like 'GLY'. But where should I post this question.

Comment: You should clarify your code and make this a coding question. We don't have access to `1UBQ.pdb`, for instance, so we have no way of knowing what is in the file. Detailed comments before each code block will not only help us understand your code and understand what each variable is and what its purpose is, but will help you down the road when you need to revisit the code for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would change this code block to use logical indexing

```
res=strsplit(p.Sequence.ResidueNames,' ');
angle =[phi;psi];
angle(:,find(strcmp(res,'GLY'))-1)=[];
```

Instead:

```
residues = strsplit(p.Sequency.ResidueNames,' ');
glycine = ismember(residues,'GLY');

angle = [phi;psi];
angleNoGLY= angle(:,~glycine);
```

Doing it this way, if you wanted to *highlight* glycine (or any other residue) you can easily call it out:

```
angleGLY = angle(:,glycine);

plot(angleNoGLY(1,:),angleNoGLY(2,:),'ob')
line(angleGLY(1,:),angleGLY(2,:),'Marker','o','Color','r','LineStyle','none')
```